# WebSocket heartbeat stops sending PING and then receives "Connection closed"

Tags: spring-websocket, stompjs

I have a Spring Boot WebSocket application that uses StompJS. There is a heartbeat setup for every 10 seconds to keep the connection alive. Periodically (maybe 2-10 minutes) the connection will be closed. The debug output from StompJS seems to indicate that `PING` requests stop getting sent, which makes me wonder if that's causing the client to think that the connection is stale and reconnects.

This is the implementation of Spring's `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.java`, setting the heartbeat to 10 seconds.

```
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic")
            .setHeartbeatValue(new long[]{ 10000, 10000 })
            .setTaskScheduler(new DefaultManagedTaskScheduler());
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
```

And this is the StompJS client setup in JavaScript, setting heartbeat to 10 seconds:

```
const stompClient = new StompJs.Client({
    heartbeatIncoming: 10000,
    heartbeatOutgoing: 10000
});
```

Below is the output from StompJS's `debug()` method. Note that the `PING` is sent every 10 seconds until the final one at `12:55:43`. The connection is closed 39 seconds later. The `PONG` message continues throughout this period.

```
12:55:22 :: Received data
12:55:22 :: <<< PONG
12:55:23 :: >>> PING
12:55:32 :: Received data
12:55:32 :: <<< PONG
12:55:33 :: >>> PING
12:55:42 :: Received data
12:55:42 :: <<< PONG
12:55:43 :: >>> PING
12:55:52 :: Received data
12:55:52 :: <<< PONG
12:56:02 :: Received data
12:56:02 :: <<< PONG
12:56:12 :: Received data
12:56:12 :: <<< PONG
12:56:22 :: Received data
12:56:22 :: <<< PONG
12:56:22 :: Connection closed to wss://example.com/ws
12:56:22 :: STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 300ms
12:56:22 :: Opening Web Socket...
12:56:22 :: Web Socket Opened...
12:56:22 :: >>> CONNECT
```

**Does the stop in `PING` messages cause the WebSocket connection to disconnect? If so, is there a way to ensure that `PING` messages continue going out?**

This is related to another question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77668892/websocket-connection-closing-unexpectedly-with-sockjs-and-spring-boot) that I might need to delete as it could be irrelevant based on this question.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be an issue with a browser tab going inactive, and the browser does not maintain the heartbeat (which the browser understandable considers expected behavior).

[Client stops sending heart beat outgoing packets · Issue #248 · stomp-js/ng2-stompjs (github.com)](https://github.com/stomp-js/ng2-stompjs/issues/248)

[[Documentation improvements] HeartBeats stops working when the tabs goes inactive on Chrome 88+ · Issue #335 · stomp-js/stompjs (github.com)](https://github.com/stomp-js/stompjs/issues/335)

My workaround will be to manually send a heartbeat from the server to the client, to keep the connection open.